# Hydro missing turtlesim/Velocity.h in the tutorial writing a tf listener

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

Ubuntu 12.04;
Ros Hydro;
C++;
link page on ROS: tf/Tutorials/Writing a tf listener (C++)

phenomenon: When I tried to follow the tutorial to write a tf listener in C++ and catkin_make it, error cannot find Velocity.h in the system.

I searched and found that there is Velocity.h in Groovy. In this page(remove turtlesim velocity and use Twist msg in Github),  jihoonl says we should change turtlesimVelocity.h to geometry_msgs/Twist.h.

How should I change the C++ tutorial code in 'writing a tf listener'? I tried to change it properly, but failed. Any suggestion is highly appreciated :)

Thank you very much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/94846/hydro-missing-turtlesim/velocity.h--in-the-tutorial-writing-a-tf-listener/) by [pymsmile](https://answers.ros.org/users/8176/pymsmile/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-10-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I know it is been a long time, but if anyone is still looking, please find the answer for changing turtlesimVelocity.h to geometry_msgs/Twist.h below:

I am using Ubuntu 16.04, ROS kinetic. Even though the answer below is specific for those trying the tutorial to write a tf listener in C++ and catkin_make (http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20listener%20(C++)), but it can be extended as well.

You need to make changes in the following four places: (please note that the lines below "old" has to be replaced with lines below "new")

//1) old

```
#include <turtlesim/Velocity.h>
```

//1) new

```
#include <geometry_msgs/Twist.h>
```

//2) old

```
  ros::Publisher turtle_vel = node.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>("turtle2/cmd_vel", 10);
```

//2) new

```
  ros::Publisher turtle_vel = node.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>("turtle2/cmd_vel", 10);
```

//3) old

```
try{
  listener.lookupTransform("/turtle2", "/turtle1",  
                           ros::Time(0), transform);
}
catch (tf::TransformException ex){
  ROS_ERROR("tf listener: %s",ex.what());
  ros::Duration(1.0).sleep();
}
```

//3) new

```
try {
    listener.waitForTransform("/turtle2", "/turtle1", ros::Time(0), ros::Duration(10.0) );
    listener.lookupTransform("/turtle2", "/turtle1", ros::Time(0), transform);
} catch (tf::TransformException ex) {
    ROS_ERROR("%s",ex.what());
}
```

//4) old

```
turtlesim::Velocity vel_msg;
vel_msg.angular = 4.0 * atan2(transform.getOrigin().y(),
                            transform.getOrigin().x());
vel_msg.linear = 0.5 * sqrt(pow(transform.getOrigin().x(), 2) +
                            pow(transform.getOrigin().y(), 2));
```

//4) new

```
geometry_msgs::Twist vel_msg;
vel_msg.angular.z = 4.0 * atan2(transform.getOrigin().y(),
                            transform.getOrigin().x());
vel_msg.linear.x = 0.5 * sqrt(pow(transform.getOrigin().x(), 2) +
                            pow(transform.getOrigin().y(), 2));
```

---

Originally posted by [balajithevoyager](https://answers.ros.org/users/30029/balajithevoyager/) with karma: 80 on 2017-04-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [balajithevoyager](https://answers.ros.org/users/30029/balajithevoyager/) on 2017-04-14**:
If anyone is getting the error "turtle2" passed to lookupTransform argument target_frame does not exist then please do the 3rd change mentioned above - add listener.waitForTransform.

**Comment by [Sparkle Eyes](https://answers.ros.org/users/38320/sparkle-eyes/) on 2019-03-31**:
Thanks so much for the answer. It helped me on the same problem.